# Gradle sets incorrect (unexpected?) classpath on running task

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

I have my project structured in this way:

```
projectRoot
  +-src
     +-main
     |   +-java
     |   |   +-package/java files go here
     |   +-resources
     |       +-config
     |           +-files go here
     +-test
         +-java
         |   +-package/java files go here
         +-resources
             +-config
             |   +-files go here
             +-features
                 +-files go here
```

When this project is built, it produces the following output structure:

```
projectRoot
  +-out
      +-production
      |     +-classes
      |     |   +-package/classes in here
      |     +-resources
      |         +-config
      |             +-files in here
      +-test
            +-classes
            |   +-package/classes in here
            +-resources
                +-config
                |   +-files in here
                +-features
                    +-files in here
```

This is all as expected. I have a task defined to run cucumber tests, which looks like this:

```
task runCucumber() {
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            args += ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--plugin', 'html:out/reports/cucumber/', '--plugin', 'json:out/reports/cucumber/report.json',
                     '--glue', 'com.example.mypackage.cucumber', 'classpath:features'
                     , '--tags', 'not @ignore']
            systemProperties['http.keepAlive'] = 'false'
            systemProperties['http.maxRedirects'] = '20'
            systemProperties['env'] = System.getProperty("env")
            systemProperties['envType'] = System.getProperty("envType")
            classpath = configurations.cucumber + configurations.compile + configurations.testCompile + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this task, my classes are not found and neither are features.  Clearly, this is due to classpath not being set correctly.  If I run the task with `--info`, I can see that the classpath is set using the parameter I indicated, however instead of `out` directories, it contains `build` directories. I expected the classpath to be:

```
<all dependencies>:/projectRoot/out/production/classses:/projectRoot/out/production/resources:/projectRoot/out/test/classes:/projectRoot/out/test/resources
```

Yet, the classpath contains the following:

```
<all dependencies>:/projectRoot/build/classes/java/main:/projectRoot/build/classes/java/test:
```

Interestingly, directory `build` is not produced at all under the project root. How can I set the classpath so that classes and resources can be found?

Comment: How are you changing the default build output directory from _build_ to _out_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turned out the issue was not with Gradle but with IntelliJ IDEA.  IDEA was overriding standard gradle paths and saving output in a different path from the one that gradle expected.  Then, when the next gradle task ran, the output wasn't there.  Compiling directly using gradle instead of IDEA solved the problem.